# How bad of an idea is it to alter a file in a pre- or post-commit hook?

Tags: version-control, svn

My team is using SVN to store a lot more than just source code - we are storing all kinds of files. A process I'm working on designing is used to generate diff reports whenever a certain Excel spreadsheet is updated *and* acknowledged by a subset of the team. (This spreadsheet is automatically generated by a separate process; no humans ever touch it.)

Here's my workflow:

1. Excel spreadsheet generated (call it `raw.xlsx`). I download the file and commit to SVN.
2. A pre-commit hook generates a new Excel spreadsheet (call it `to_review.xlsx`) and commits *that*. An email gets sent to my team saying that a diff between `raw.xlsx:HEAD` and `raw.xlsx:PREV` was detected.
3. Someone on my team reviews `to_review.xlsx`, edits as needed, and commits it.
4. A pre- or post-commit hook *then makes edits to* `to_review.xlsx` to update a tab to reflect the edits, and commits *that*. (Optionally: fire an email saying that you need to now update your working copy of `to_review.xlsx`.) It also generates a file `report.pdf` that summarizes the diff of `raw.xlsx:HEAD` and `raw.xlsx:PREV`.

How okay or not-okay is it to use SVN in this manner - i.e., to edit the file a human just committed and re-commit it? The edit will never be against what the human added/removed, but by doing this the human immediately has an out-of-date copy as soon as he commits. I'm not sure how else to approach this - we can't go straight from `raw.xlsx` to `report.pdf`, a human must be in the loop with `to_review.xlsx`.

Comment: You are using SVN as a file repository with versioning. At every step, I believe that you are doing the right thing, so there is a clear, auditable trail of changes to all of the files of interest. What the hooks are doing is triggering work flows. You could do the same sorts of things on a Sharepoint server or Alfresco server using work flows and versioned file nodes, but undoubtedly for you, SVN is cheaper and has a shorter learning curve.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please feel free to edit the question or ask me to clarify if the question can be improved.

Comment: @DangKhoa: your question is fine (and is a valid one). Supposedly, the downvoter assumed that the question is off-topic, missing the fact that [questions about build tools are on-topic here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It happens occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

The question is more about your reasonable, and automated, review process.

Commit hooks are used to make well defined changes to files. Examples could be line endings, and insertion of updated boilerplate text. I am not sure if RCS tags are expanded in the SVN saved file rather depends on your version control system.
Hooks can also be used to reject invalid changes.

The use of commit hooks as described doesn't seem to fit into that category. The hooks delay commit and trigger changes in other files. 
There also seems to be a flaw if two people submit changes to raw.xlsx.

Is there any reason why you cannot use post-commit hooks to trigger your process without directly modifying the affected file ?

So, you submit raw.xlsx. It is saved and then causes the to_review.xlsx process.

Assuming you are allowed to reject a review the hook for that *could* overwrite the raw.xlsx with the preceding version. From the process description its not that clear what purposes the archive of raw.xlsx versions would be used for.